# Is the definition of a sheaf in Serre's paper "Coherent Algebraic Sheaves" equivalent to the standard definition?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

In Serre's paper "Coherent Algebraic Sheaves", the definition of a sheaf is so different from other book's I have ever seen. I want to know whether it is equivalent to the standard definition.

Comment: Yes, it is; see remark 2.2.11 of Vakil's notes, for example.

Comment: Yes it is. If I remember correctly this is one of the first things he proves also. I think standard here is subjective also as Serre's définition (as the étale space) is standard in a lot of places (not Hartshorne however).